# Pipes and fork - scanf is reading only one character

Tags: c, linux, fork, pipe, scanf

I have a task to write 3 proccesses connected together with pipes. 1st one should read input from user, 2nd should read from 1st and make letters uppercase, 3 should read from 2nd and print the result. The problem is that scanf reads only first pressed character and then the programs end. What I've done wrong? I tried to send hardcoded string and it worked just fine.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#define ODCZYT 0
#define ZAPIS 1

int main(){
        char readbuffer[80];
        char tempbuffer[80];
        char printbuffer[80];
        int i=0;

        int potok[2];
        int potok2[2];
        pid_t pid_A, pid_B, pid_C;

        pipe( potok );
        pipe( potok2);
        puts( "fork" );
        if(!(pid_A = fork()) )
        {

                puts("Podaj string:");
                close(potok[ODCZYT]);
                close(potok2[ODCZYT]);
                close(potok2[ZAPIS]);
                scanf( "%s", readbuffer )
                write(potok[ZAPIS],readbuffer, sizeof(readbuffer));    
                close(potok[ZAPIS]);
        }
        if(!(pid_B = fork()) )
        {
                close( potok[ZAPIS] );
                close(potok2[ODCZYT]);
                read( potok[ODCZYT], tempbuffer, sizeof(tempbuffer));
                close(potok[ODCZYT]);
                while(tempbuffer[i]){
                        tempbuffer[i]=toupper(tempbuffer[i]);          
                        i++;                   
                }
                write(potok2[ZAPIS],tempbuffer, sizeof(tempbuffer));
                close(potok2[ZAPIS]);
        }
        if( !(pid_C = fork()) ) {

                close(potok[ODCZYT]);
                close(potok[ZAPIS]);
                close(potok2[ZAPIS]);
                read( potok2[ODCZYT], printbuffer, sizeof(printbuffer));
                puts(printbuffer);
                close(potok2[ODCZYT]);

        }
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have multiple minor errors, a handful of which were answered below.  First and foremost you *have* to learn to check your return codes.  When and if you do many things will become clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question code might be doing more that expected.  Instead of creating 3 processes, it is creating 7 processes, not including the `main()` process, which is actually 8 processes total.

The thread [main()] does create threads [A], [B] and [C].

Thread [A] does the work within the first `if` block, then goes on and creates threads [B1] and [C1].

Thread [B] does the work within the second`if` block, then goes on and creates threads [C2].

Thread [B1] does the work within the second `if` block, then goes on and creates threads [C3].

To review, the total threads include [main()], [A], [B], [C], [B1], [C1], [C2] & [C3].

This is not what the question description indicated.

---

To fix the code, place a `return(0)` statement at the bottom of each 'if' block, which will cause each thread to perform only the tasks within it's 'if' block.

---

And a small correction... Change:

```
scanf( "%s", readbuffer )
```

to:

```
scanf( "%s", readbuffer );  //<-- Add semicolon
```

---

Create a `test.txt` file with the content:

```
uppercase
```

Then run the program:

```
> ./test < test.txt
```

Results in printing 'UPPERCASE'

---

***Why is scanf() only reading one character when input is from the keyboard, but works when reading from a file?***

The problem is a thread syncronization issue.  Thread[main()] terminates, and the shell program (ie: Bash, etc.,) tries to regain control; but thread[A]'s scanf() requires an event (such as an incoming character) before it will realize that it's time to terminate (and terminate).  As soon as a key is pressed, thread[A] gobbles it up, but then thread[A] immediately terminates without processing the character from the keyboard. *`scanf()` never actually returns!* As soon as thread[A] terminates, the shell program (ie: Bash, etc.,) re-gains control of the keyboard.

***How to fix this?***

Have thread[main()] wait for thread[C] to terminate.  Change the end of the program, adding a `waitpid()` call:

```
   waitpid(pid_C, NULL, 0);

   return(0);
```

(Of course, in order to reference `waitpid()`, you will have to add the appropriate .h file(s).)

---

Fixed code can be found at: http://www.mahonri.info/SO/23743011_pipes-and-fork-scanf-is-reading-only-one-character.c
       }

Answer (score 0):

read() and write() aren't guaranteed to return all of the bytes you've asked for. Check the return values of your read() and write() calls to see how many characters were actually read and written. You may need to loop to get all of them. Also, I didn't run your snippet, but you don't do anything with the parent processes. You need to exit the parent at the end of each conditional to prevent it from running the next section, which could have bad consequences.